# comparing two array in ksh script

Tags: shell, ksh

Code snippet is here:

```
  #!/usr/bin/ksh

   diff(){
     awk 'BEGIN {RS=ORS= }
            {NR==FNR?a[$0]++:a[$0]--}
                   END{for(k in a)if(a[k])print k}' < (echo -n "${!1}") < (echo -n "${!2}")
   }

                   Array1=( key1 key2 key3 key4 key5 key6 key7 key8 key9 key10 )
                  Array2=( key1 key2 key3 key4 key5 key6 )
                  Array3=($(diff Array1[@] Array2[@]))
                  echo ${Array3[@]}
```

and I am facing the error

```
syntax error at line 6 : `(' unexpected
```

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate what OS you are using, i.e. AIX/Solaris/HP or other Unixen. If you're using Linux, please edit it the value returned by `echo ${.sh.version}`. If  you're using an old-line Unix as listed here (and  others), you're almost certainly using ksh88, which doesn't support all the syntax you're using above. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The sytax error you mention is becuase of the space after the `<`, for process substitution you should use:

```
<(echo -n "${1}") <(echo -n "${2}")
```

The `!` is highly dubious (I get a syntax error), and I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Also, you are not passing the arrays into the function, just their names.  Did you mean:

```
Array3=($(diff "${Array1[@]}" "${Array2[@]}"))
```

Of course you cannot pass arrays into functions, only lists.

It is a bad idea to call your own function `diff`, since there is a standard utility program with the same name which could cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to compare two arrays together and find the differences which can be accomplished by [associative arrays in AWK or KSH](http://microdevsys.com/wp/awk-for-human-beings/).  However I'm not 100% certain if you won't encounter some KSH array size limitation if you're looking at even larger sets.  (Or I'm wrong.)

```
KSH:
typeset -A aArray;                                      # Declare
aArray=([this]=1 [that]=2 [who]=3 [what]=4 [where]=5);  # Assign
print ${aArray[@]}                                      # Print out the elements.
print ${aArray[one]}                                    # Index

AWK:
aArray["this"]=1;aArray["that"]=2;aArray["who"]=3;aArray["what"]=4;aArray["where"]=5;  # Declare
for ( KEY in aArray ) print KEY" Value at KEY: "aArray[KEY];                                                       # Print
```

Cheers,
TK